# Slim, scissor-switch, non-chiclet (old ThinkPad-like) wired (USB) keyboard

Tags: keyboards

**UPDATE**: even though I have accepted an answer, I will be very happy for any other suggestions.

---

I've been a frequent laptop user for years and whenever I needed a new desktop keyboard I managed to get a laptop-like (think ThinkPad x220 or *older*) keyboard that had:

- low-profile keys which come with low travel distance
- non-chiclet keys - i.e keys bordering each other, without any borders formed by the top of the keyboard body
- scissor switches, which provide reasonable key stability
- wired connection, which is more secure than whatever wireless one I've ever seen
- generally recognisable 104±1 keys layout (I'm not picky about the exact <kbd>Enter</kbd> / <kbd></kbd> / Backspace</kbd> placement, just prefer them to be close to each other).
- I would prefer "classical" key labels, i.e.:
- symbols slightly in the corner
- a decent (non-gaming/futuristic) font

Recently, I'm unable to find anything like that - non-chiclet keyboards I have seen usually have too long travel distance.

Acceptable disadvantages:

- Layouts where the arrow block is pushed into the main block and the 6-kay block above it rearranged somehow.
- Multimedia buttons (if they are there I either use them or switch them off on software level).

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a wired Cherry Stream JK-8500 keyboard, which I can recommend.

It has some multimedia keys, but fortunately they do not occupy or overlap with the positions of any standard keys. That aside, it meets all your criteria.

Comment: Can you share a link to the specific model?

Comment: Yes, it's this one: https://www.amazon.com/CHERRY-Stream-Keyboard-Scissors-Mechanism/dp/B07Z1KH3PL (strictly speaking, that is a JK-8500EU-2, mine is the Nordic version JK-8500PN-2 which has 1 extra key)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with exactly the same for the moment :)